# VTune using Windows embedded OS

Tags: intel, intel-vtune

I am wondering if it is possible to use VTune 2013 or VTune2015 using a Windows embedded operating system. I read on the release notes that "embedded editions not supported" but I would like to know if there is a way for example to collect data on a Windows embedded system and view results on standard windows system and/or to perform remote mode using Windows embedded target.

Thanks,

Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

VTune 2015 effective Update 3 can be used on subset of Windows Embedded variants: Windows Embedded **Standard**, Windows Embedded **Pro**
and Windows Embedded **Industry**.

Other variants like Windows Embedded Compact and Windows Embedded Handheld are not supported by VTune as they differ substantially from desktop Windows.

Regards,
Katya

Comment: Where do you get this info? Because in the release note of the update 3 ( and 4) it is explicitly said that embedded editions are not supported

Comment: We in VTune team performed touch testing on the specified subset of embedded OS, and added several fixes in Update 3 to allow pre-defined analysis usage. To claim official support and update release notes - we need to explore more aspects and specific of Windows embeeded support.

Comment: From Intel support: If your embedded system has no disk space restricted, you can extract VTune Amplifier XE package (e.g. "VTune_Amplifier_XE_2015_setup.exe --extract-only --silent --extract-folder C:\temp\VTune_Amplifier_XE_2015_unpacked") then install it (e.g. run "Amplifier_XE.msi" with Administrative privileges) on the target.

vtune drivers might or might not work, user-mode sampling collection can work I guess. Note that your target system hasn't been tested and have no technical support for now, it is your risk to run this product on unsupported operation system.